# Is this no-collision-type hash algorithm safe?

Tags: hashing

I've designed a hash algorithm based on mathematical exponentiation, exponentiating each number by its following number. To be able to exponentiate indefinitely, numbers are first normalized to a 0-1 range. Then, to preserve the ordering characteristic even when normalized, the mean of the list is taken before hashing and prepended to the list.

Also:

- Zeroes are substituted by the mean to prevent stabilization around zero values and zero results for leading-zero lists
- Inputs are normalized to absolutes to avoid producing complex numbers, since mean is changed
- All-zero lists are checked and return zero
- The resulting value is a double in the 0-1 range.

It's been tested on large and small magnitude lists of floats, as well as showing zero collisions in a 446,000 word test.

Does this mean it has zero collisions?

Comment: see [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: You may be interested in providing the comparison with the default hashing algorithm in from .NET Framework. Reading the GitHub description, my first reaction was: “Well, the author doesn't cite any benefit for me to use his algorithm instead of the default one; aside, he talks about ‘possibly very low collision rate’ without giving the actual metrics, and about performance, without doing the actual performance comparisons.”

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko the collision and performance test cited are available [here](https://psobo.com/blog/exponentiation_based_float_hash_2.html).

Comment: @pedroos: maybe. But this information is so crucial that it should be included in the README on GitHub. Most people who hit your project on GitHub won't follow the links. Blog articles are useful for people who are already interested in your project and want to learn more; in order for them to be interested, you need to convince them *first* that the project is useful.

Comment: "no-collision hash algorithm" - yeah that sounds a bit questionable

Comment: @whatisname, there's no actual claim of no collisions.

Comment: Besides the fact such a question should contain a minimum of pseudocode and/or mathematical formulas to describe the hash function, what precisely do you mean by "safe"? Please clarify (ideally with a strict definition).

Comment: What you've shown is some nice mathematical experiment, so it's great that you're pursuing this. However, please understand that this has zero application as a real-world hashing algorithm. You're thinking in terms of real numbers, but hash functions in computer science operate on bit strings. Current high-quality non-crypto hash functions also run way faster than anything exponentiation-based, often just using bit-shifts (to introduce asymmetry and disperse bits downwards), xors (to combine bits), and multiplication by a constant prime (to disperse bits upwards).

Comment: @DocBrown all specific steps taken by the algorithm have now been included in the question (no formulas). Also, by "safe" I mean to question how to evaluate how many collisions it produces in practice, as tests run so far have resulted in zero.

Comment: @amon I'd like to quantify the mentioned quality in terms of collisions. Performance is not a consideration.

Comment: The link to your GH is broken. But please read [this related work](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/07/31/#the-measure-of-a-hash-function) on designing integer hash functions. After all, the difference between a double and 64 bit int is just a reinterpret-cast. It suggests two quality metrics (avalanche effect, correlation) and a technique to measure them. You will e.g. find that the bits in the double's exponent are largely discarded due to your normalization. For experiencing collisions it can also help to use 32 bit floats instead of doubles.

Comment: @amon Link restablished.

Comment: (Advice.) For the type of work you did, one way to get more publicity and insightful feedback from professionals is to share your blog post on Hacker News as a "Show HN"-type post. Please use each online venue according to their purpose. If something is more suitable on Hacker News (but not suitable on Software Engineering on Stack Exchange), then please post on HN instead.

Comment: @pedroos: accepting an answer which does not fit to your question is very confusing for other readers.

Comment: @rwong I don't think I asked for publicity in my original or edited question, That's why it was not asked on a 'publicity' website.

Comment: @DocBrown A premise in the original question was wrong. I don't know if a new question should be opened.

Comment: I've reverted the question to the original title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. By definition, reducing N doubles to a single double hash will produce collisions. You just don’t have enough bits to represent all of the combinations.

Comment: The question text was changed, so it should be clear now this answer does not fit (it actually never did, since it misinterpreted what the OP meant by "safe" in the original question).

Comment: Which makes it even more curious that it is accepted :-D

Comment: The original title has been reinstated.